# Do the Zariel tiefling's subrace bonuses stack with the tiefling's regular racial bonuses?

Tags: dnd-5e, races, ability-scores, racial-traits

I'm rather new to D&D and I've been trying to create a Tiefling Paladin. When I looked through the subraces, I saw the Zariel tiefling and thought it to be a good idea, which my friends agreed to.

When I saw it, though, it seems unfair to have +1 Strength, +1 Intellect and +4 Charisma. I asked my friends and they didn't know.

**Am I calculating the ability score increases for the Zariel tiefling wrong?**

Answer (score 34):

*Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes* introduces tiefling subraces which have a special link to one of the Lords of the Nine Hells, one of which is Zariel. Below the [Subrace Traits](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/mtof/the-blood-war#SubraceTraits) heading (MToF, p. 21), it states:

> The traits of the chosen subrace **replace** the tiefling's Ability
>   Score Increase and Infernal Legacy traits given in the *Player's
>   Handbook*. (emphasis mine)

Thus, the [Zariel tiefling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/races/tiefling#ZarielTiefling) subrace will only get a total racial ability score increase of +1 Str and +2 Cha.